# How to obtain pdf of a RV that each experiment depends on result of previous experiment

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, independence

Let assume that Random Variables (RVs) $X$ , $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ have i.i.d. uniform distribution over [0,A]. Let assume $D = Min( X-X_{1} , X-X_{2})$ and after each experiment, right most of RVs $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ moves to the position of RV $X$ and other remains fixed. RV X generates on each new experiment. How I compute pdf of RV $D$?
I guess that one method is using Markov chains (MCs) but MCs is similar to Moore machine (state diagram) but in this problem RV $D$ is output of Mealy machine.
An example with three consecutive iterations is as following figure:
[image]

Comment: What does "right most of RVs $X_1$ and $X_2$ moves to the position of rv X" mean?  Right most of what? What position does X hold?

Comment: A figure is added for clarifying the question.